# Does Morbo ever make good on his statements?

Tags: aliens, futurama

[Morbo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recurring_characters_in_Futurama#Morbo) refers to himself as 'the Annihilator' and frequently threatens mankind.

Has he or his species ever made good on his threats? Or is Linda right in dismissing him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the series, neither [Morbo](http://theinfosphere.org/Morbo) nor any other [Morboian](http://theinfosphere.org/Morboians) is shown destroying mankind (or anything else, for that matter). However, if you consider promotional collectors' items like [animation cels](http://theinfosphere.org/Futurama_animation_cel) as canon (not really), then Morbo is a man... err, Morboian of his word:

[image]

Comment: When is this supposed to happen?

Comment: It hasn't. This is a promotional animation cell, done as a collector's item, depicting Morbo's final rampage against a helpless Earth. Yeah, that's how Morbo pictures it in his head anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Morbo's comments seem to be a setup to a plot that has not happened yet. Whether the writers want Morbo's people to attack the Earth or whether it is just a joke and his threats should not be taken seriously is completely up to them. My fingers are crossed that something has happened to his people and he does not know it yet.