# Is Morbo serious?

Tags: futurama

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Morbo ever make good on his statements?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18254/does-morbo-ever-make-good-on-his-statements)

Whenever he is seen on the show, [Morbo](http://theinfosphere.org/Morbo)
often openly regards humans to be of an inferior species, and often seems to imply that his race will conquer theirs. Furthermore he once threatened to destroy his wife while she was fixing his tie for him.

My question is this: is Morbo's really intent on attacking Earth someday? Is he forced to say these things as a way to attract viewers' attention? Or is it all just the way his species blusters (similar to the way we would say how we're going to "kill" someone, even if we've never committed nor intended to commit murder)?

Answer (score 0):

He certainly wants to... but I think since he got here he's grown to enjoy the pleasures of Earth. He'll get around to the utter domination of our planet eventually, but right now there are better things to do.